# Postgres - ERROR: syntax error at or near "IF" inside stored procedure

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, conditional-statements, psql

I'm trying to condition if the new role I am receiving from parameter is equal to "ADMIN", if it is `true` then execute 2 queries, those type of queries are `UPDATE` and `INSERT INTO`. But I found some questions on here like mine and I tried to solve it, but finally I couldn't solve it.

This is the chunk I am trying to run:

```
-- ROLE MEMBER UPDATER

CREATE PROCEDURE actualizador_roles 
    (from_email varchar,
     to_email varchar,
     new_role varchar) 
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$

    UPDATE member 
    SET role = new_role 
    WHERE email = to_email;

    INSERT INTO database_activity (from_email, to_member, activity, affected_table, role, date) 
    VALUES (from_email, to_email, CONCAT('ROLE UPDATED TO ', new_role), 'member', (SELECT role FROM member WHERE email = from_email), now());

    BEGIN

        IF new_role = 'ADMIN' THEN 
        BEGIN
            UPDATE membership 
            SET started = NULL, finished = NULL, status = 'ACTIVA' 
            WHERE email_member = to_email;

            INSERT INTO database_activity (from_email, to_member, activity, affected_table, role, date) 
            VALUES (from_email, to_email, 'STARTED AND FINISHED DATE UPDATED TO NULL AND STATUS ACTIVA', 'membership', (SELECT role FROM member WHERE email = from_email), now());
        END IF;
    END;
$$;
```

Error returned:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "IF"
> LINE 13: IF new_role = 'ADMIN' THEN
> ^
> SQL state: 42601
> Character: 418

How can I execute 2 queries if the condition is true?

Comment: **As update to question**: 1) Show the complete procedure. 2) Show the complete error message.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver i did it! check it out and thanks for your interest.

Comment: You can't use conditionals(or `BEGIN/END`) with `sql` functions. If you want to do this you need to use [plpgsql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html).

Comment: Got it, I will investigate how to condition that values. Thanks man for answering quickly!

Comment: Change `LANGUAGE SQL` to `LANGUAGE plgsql`.

Comment: I changed it, but now return as error: ```ERROR:  language "plgsql" does not exist
SQL state: 42704```

Comment: That would be because I was not paying attention to spelling, it should be `plpgsql`.

Comment: In PL/pgSQL you also need a `begin ... end;` around the complete function (so after the first `$$` and before the ending `$$`